# Execute commands after connection to remote SSH terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I am using VSCode `Remote - SSH Connect To Host`.

I've tried to use `tasks` to execute commands after connect but it spawns a new shell.

How can I execute arbitrary shell commands on the remote shell after connection?